# How to avoid UI flickering in windows CE application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-ce

I am developing an application in windows CE 5.0 using c# .net with visual studio 2008.
I want to display some user controls in main user control by create user control object.
While loading user controls in main user control, the application is flickering.

For example I have 1 user control which has 1 button image, I want to display 20 buttons of this user control.

` protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            //base.OnPaint(e);
            Graphics gxOff = e.Graphics;
            Graphics g;

```
        //Paint the string
        Font boldFont = new Font("Tahoma", 8.0F, FontStyle.Bold);
        Color penColor = Color.FromArgb(48, 48, 48);

        StringFormat drawFormat = new StringFormat();
        drawFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        if (m_bmpOffscreen == null) //Bitmap for doublebuffering
        {
            m_bmpOffscreen = new Bitmap(this.ClientRectangle.Width, this.ClientRectangle.Height);
        }

        g = Graphics.FromImage(m_bmpOffscreen);

        g.Clear(this.BackColor);

        if (!Disabled)
        {
            backgroundImage = unselected_img;
            if (selected)
            {
                backgroundImage = selected_img;
                g.DrawImage(backgroundImage, this.ClientRectangle, new Rectangle(0, 0, backgroundImage.Width, backgroundImage.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            }
            else
                g.DrawImage(backgroundImage, this.ClientRectangle, new Rectangle(0, 0, backgroundImage.Width, backgroundImage.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
        else
        {
            backgroundImage = disabled_img;
            g.DrawImage(backgroundImage, this.ClientRectangle, new Rectangle(0, 0, backgroundImage.Width, backgroundImage.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }

        g.DrawString(this.Content, boldFont, new SolidBrush(penColor), new RectangleF(0, 3, 20, 20), drawFormat);

        gxOff.DrawImage(m_bmpOffscreen, 0, 0);
    }`
```

Please help to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: using docking, panels, any layout panels in for controls in user control and for user controls?

Comment: I am drawing button image in onpaint event in user control which I am trying to load in another user control

Comment: So show your drawing code. Also i think add 20 user controls which draws something is not good idea.

Comment: I want to display Same user control with different content. I have added 20 user controls of this type with different content, while loading at the first time it is flickering. I also tried double buffering.

Comment: can you post your drawing code?

Comment: If you just drawing something in user control, so you better think about creating custom control. User control is better to (lets say) "hold" collection of controls. [Read here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rprabhu/archive/2003/10/23/56549.aspx) to get more information about differences(last two sentences is the resume).

Comment: Ya I tried with custom control

Comment: also try to disable onpaintbackground it may also cause flickering

Comment: This code is in custom control which I am adding in user control, user control don't have the paint methods

Comment: so try to override onpaintbackground and remove call to base onpaintbackground i read somewhere that it helps some times to avoid flickering

Comment: Yes I have tried, that is not working

Answer (score 0):

Your back buffer code looks fine, though I'd recommend keeping your Graphics object around.  You can dispose and update it and the back buffer Bitmap in OnResize - be sure to check valid size.  I suspect you might be seeing flickering from default behavior of OnPaintBackground, try to override and no-op it.